# performing mathematical operations on data read using dataset from a sql server database

Tags: dataset

I have a database on sql server. The table regarding which i have to ask question is as follows:
It has 4 columns:(table name:votes)

**id** bigint notnull primary key
**optAvotes** bigint notnull
**optBvotes** bigint notnull
**optCvotes** bigint notnull
I want to perform mathematical operations on these column values like addition, percentage calculation etc. I am doing it like this:

```
dim da as new sqldataadapter("select * from votes",con)
dim ds as new dataset
da.fill(ds)
dim A,B,C,Total as integer
A=ds.tables(0).rows(0).item("optAvotes").tostring
B=ds.tables(0).rows(0).item("optBvotes").tostring
C=ds.tables(0).rows(0).item("optCvotes").tostring
Total=A+B+C
```

When i display the value of Total it shows an error that is **conversion from string "**
Whereas if i declare these variables as string then Total=A+B+C displays result as a concatenated string. So please tell me the solution as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total is an integer and will not accept a string. You need to convert A,B,C from string to integer before you add them and assign the integer result to Total.

try :

```
Total = Convert.ToInt32(A) + Convert.ToInt32(B) + Convert.ToInt32(C)
```

OR

```
Total = CInt(A) + CInt(B) + CInt(C)
```